# "After looking after myself and my" or "After looking after me and my"?

Tags: grammar

"After looking after me and my pet, I..."

or

"After looking after myself and my pet, I..."

Does the pronoun "I" not need to be placed at the beginning of a sentence in order to use the reflexive "myself"? Or is it fine to use when "I" immediately follows as it does here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226/my-wife-and-is-seafood-collaboration-dinner)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not sure the duplicate you indicate has anything to do with this question. Was it a typo?

Comment: *After looking after **I and my wife's** pet...* ? If that's not close enough to be a valid duplicate, I'd vote to migrate to ELL. I don't think many native Anglophones agonise much over matters like this.

Answer (score 3):

No, a sentence using *myself* does not have to begin with *I*, though it normally contains it.

Your first version is wrong, though. I look after *myself*, but someone else looks after *me.*

Comment: And let's reword *After looking after*.

Answer (score 2):

Since ***I*** am doing the *looking*, you have no choice but use ***myself***. Your first sentence is ungrammatical.

Your second sentence (which is the correct one) is a case of ***cataphora***:

> In English grammar, *cataphora* is *the use of a pronoun or other linguistic unit to refer **ahead** to another word in a sentence* (i.e., the referent). Also known as anticipatory anaphora, forward anaphora, cataphoric reference, or forward reference. ([Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-cataphora-grammar-1689829))

Cataphora is definitely less frequent than ***[anaphora](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-anaphora-grammar-1689093)***, but it has a fairly common usage. Here are some examples (from Thought.co):

> - A few weeks before ***he*** died, ***my father*** gave me an old cigar box filled with faded letters.
> - ***It*** must have been tough on your mother, ***not having any children***.
> - Too scared to buy before ***they*** sell, ***some homeowners*** aim for a trade.

So there is nothing wrong with using ***myself***, before mentioning ***I***. To avoid repetition, your sentence could better be formulated as follows:

> Having looked after myself and my pet, I...